# ARM Cortex-A9 Software generated interrupt only triggered once

Tags: arm, interrupt, cortex-a

I'm working with ARM Cortex-A9 in a Zynq7020 and having problem with software generated interrupts.

When I generate (writing to the ICDSGIR register) a SGI in core ARM1 it is only triggered once and not again, more writes to ICDSGIR does not trigger the interrupt.

Generating a SGI in core ARM0 sent to ARM1 works fine but not ARM1 to ARM1.

Is there any special handling needed for SGI in the ISR? What could I have missed in the configuration?

Comment: What OS are you using?  What is the interrupt driver doing?  These can be masked.  Each GIC has a private copy of some of the registers.

Comment: Are you writing the indicated id back to GICC_EOIR at the end of your interrupt handler?

Comment: @ unixsmurf: Thank you! That solved the problem, I had not realized that this was needed as the SGI from ARM0 worked fine. I would mark your comment as an answer if I could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should mark the end of interrupt by writing the interrupt ID along with the target processor to the **ICCEOIR** register:

[image: ICCEOIR register]